# how to keep a subscription open between routes?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

How do i keep a subscription open between different calls to the IronRouter routes?

I have an app that has a hierarchy like a magazine, issue/page

```
content/:issue/:page
```

so this would be:

```
content/may/page1
content/may/page2
content/may/page3
```

I would like to load all the content for "May" issue within the router, and when the pages are changed NOT do an unsubscribe. I am seeing some flicker with the app which I think is caused by delay as the data is being reconnected to.

I currently have a simple Content.find({}) but there is an apparent delay seeming to be caused by the unsub/pub/sub handshake - even though the content is not changing.

Update: I moved the subscribe outside of IronRouter routes entirely and now it seems "sticky". However i imagine subscriptions are getting unsubscribed somewhere, so I'm not sure if this is the best solution. It is also now a global subscribe" whereas really i want to be able to control pub/unsub only if the `:issue` parameter has changed on that route.

Comment: Maybe have a look at [subscriptions-manager](http://meteorhacks.com/subscriptions-manager-is-here.html).

Comment: thanks, didn't know about that and seems to do what i want. Arunoda is a machine! Also confirms my suspicions that subscriptions were getting closed, despite not seeming to be...

Answer (score 0):

Handling subscriptions on a template level is far superior to handeling it in the router.

Because when you handle it in the router the page only gets loaded after the subscription is ready. Which makes your application feel less responsive.

Template:

```
<template name="example">
   {{#with data=getData}}
        {{#if $not data.ready}}
             {{> spinner}} Loading...
        {{/if}}
   {{/with}}
</template>
```

Template helper:

```
Template.example.getData = function() {
    var ready = Meteor.subscribe('someSubscription', this.issueId).ready();
    var data = collections.example.find();

    return {
        ready: ready,
        data: data
    };
};
```

This results in a more responsively feeling application. It is always better to avoid a slow/bad/nonresponsive design, before resorting to something like caching to fix a problem with the used design.